# Deleting HTML elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue adding a delete button to elements in a form I'm building. The last function `deleteField()` is giving me trouble. It is not accepting the event or color elements when I try to delete.

Why won't it accept the elements as a node when it is a subset of the node class?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName, isUpdate, eventId, color){
    var dropdown = document.createElement('select');
    var color_field = document.createElement('INPUT');
    var delete_button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var x  = document.createTextNode("X");
    delete_button.onclick = deleteField(divName, counter);

    color_field.setAttribute("type", "color");
    color_field.name = "color[" + counter + "]";
    color_field.id   = "c"+i;
    if(isUpdate) {
        color_field.value = color;
    }
    @eventList.map { event =>
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "@event.getId";
        option.text  = "@event.getTitle";
        dropdown.add(option);}
        dropdown.name = "event[" + counter + "]";
        dropdown.id   = "e" + counter;
    color_field.appendChild(x);
    var doc = document.getElementById(divName);
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(document.createTextNode("Set event #" + counter));
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(dropdown);
    if(isUpdate){dropdown.value = eventId};
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(color_field);
    document.getElementbyId(divName).appendChild(delete_button);
    counter++;
    }

function setInput(divName){
    @existing_list.map { eventItem =>
        addInput(divName, true, @eventItem._1, '@eventItem._2.getOrElse("#000000")')
    }
}

    **function deleteField(divName, i){
        var parent = document.getElementById(divName);
        var event = document.getElementById("e"+i);
        var color = document.getElementById("c"+i);
        parent.removeChild(event);
        parentremoveChild(color);**
```

Comment: Please create an executable code.

Comment: `delete_button.onclick = deleteField(divName, counter);` this immediately  executes `deleteField(...)` and assigns the return value (`undefined`) to `.onclick`;

Comment: Please define " It is not accepting the event or color elements". Do you get an error?

Comment: Bottom line `parentremoveChild(color);` should be `parent.removeChild(color);`

Answer (score 1):

> The last function deleteField() is giving me trouble. It is not accepting the event or color elements when I try to delete.

Bottom line `parentremoveChild(color);` should be `parent.removeChild(color);`